# Windows Server 2012 missing disk space

Tags: disk-space, windows-server-2012-r2, disk-management

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZJjJ.jpg]

[image: disk management screenshots]

My Windows Server 2012 is missing disk space. I'm completely lost here, have no clue where the other 20 GBs have gone.

Could anyone assist me?

Comment: I would suggest that you open `diskmgmt.msc` via the Run... command to get a better indication of what the actual allocation is.

Comment: In diskmgmt.msc I get the same information.
http://i.imgur.com/Vagt6t9.jpg

Comment: Is it running as a virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, It is a Virtual Private Server.

Comment: I think that the disk may be set as dynamically expanding which means it hasn't allocated the 40GB on the host yet. You can test copying some files to see if the useable capacity really is 40GB. Certainly this is the way it works with dynamically allocated RAM if using Windows Server Hypervisor to host the VM's and it makes it very confusing to track resources in the guest OS.

Comment: Either that or the file system is completely messed up, you could try using chkdsk (Windows built in disk checking tool) to check for any issues.

Comment: Run a chkdsk/r, there is probably a disk freespace issue. you may have to run chkdsk more than once.

Comment: Isn't there any RAID created?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would check that the file system isn't corrupt as you could run into all sorts of issues. Please try using `chkdsk` (Windows built in disk checking tool) to check:

- Open a command prompt as administrator
- Type `chkdsk C: /F` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- It may well inform you that it cannot lock the volume and requires a scheduled check at boot time, in which case enter `Y` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll need the server/VM to be rebooted for the check to go ahead and obviously there will be some down-time.

---

If this doesn't work you could try the procedure below. **I would recommend getting a full backup done beforehand though**

- Open a command prompt as administrator
- Type `diskpart` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. A new command-prompt should appear.
- At the `DISKPART>` prompt, type `list volume` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will show all the volumes on the system
- Type `select volume #` (where # is the number of the relevant volume) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type `extend filesystem` and and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This should adjust the filesystem to use all available capacity in the volume and is based on several articles on the web, including [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832316).

If that *still* doesn't work, you could try repeating the above but use `extend` instead of `extend filesystem` as this will extend the volume itself if there is unallocated space on the disk. But I don't think that is the issue.